# Jackson bi-directional nested object setting

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, jackson

I'm having a few issues with deserializing the following json:

```
{
    children:[{name:"1c"},{name:"2c"},{name:"3c"}]
}
```

My classes would look like this:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(scope=ParentObject.class,generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
public class ParentObject {
 int id;
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="parent",orphanRemoval=true)
 Set<Child> children;
}

@JsonIdentityInfo(scope=Child.class,generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
public class Child {
 int id;
 String name;
 @ManyToOne
 ParentObject parent;
}
```

With this in mind,  I'd like Jackson to automatically set the ParentObject.

The structure I'm given is almost perfect with the exception of the ParentObject not being set. This is imperative as Hibernate will then set the ids of the parent and then set the ids of the children based on this which is currenly null.

I originally had it set with a JSONManagedReference and BackReference, but that it uni-directional and when requesting a single object, the parent object would be ignored.

How can I get this to work?
Thanks!
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using @jsonignore on the 
@ManyToOne
 ParentObject parent;

I think while deserializing it will not consider it and give you a Parent Object..

Regards,

Prasad